# USA Road Network Data Set Options?

Tags: data, network, united-states, road

I need a contiguous, nationwide USA Road Network with speed limits, distances, etc.  I have been using TIGER but the challenge is at state boundaries - where contiguous road segments are split.

Is there any free or commercially available data set that provides this data, besides ESRI/ArcGIS?

Comment: You may want to consider researching/asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Could you join roads at the boundaries?

Comment: Iant - thank you for the suggestion.  How would I go about doing that in ArcGIS or some other similar tool?